# Flutter FireStore the orderBy and where queries causing error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

This is simple query

```
_firestore
        .collection('workerField')
        .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: getCurrentUser().uid)
        .orderBy('orderBy',descending: true)
```

And I get this error:

> The following assertion was thrown building BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>#d3204):
>
> The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([orderBy]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([uid])" when an inequality operator is invoked.
>
> 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 252 pos 18: 'field == orders[0][0]'